# Swift lazy instantiating using self

Tags: swift, initialization, lazy-initialization

I have something that really puzzles me, specifically the following code triggers a compiler error "unresolved identifier self", and I am not sure why this is happening, as lazy means that at the time the property will be used, the class is already instantiated. Am I missing something?

Many thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
class FirstClass {
    unowned var second: SecondClass

    init(second:SecondClass) {
        self.second = second
        print("First reporting for duty")
    }

    func aMethod() {
        print("First's method reporting for duty")
    }
}


class SecondClass {

    lazy var first = FirstClass(second: self)

    func aMethod() {
        first.aMethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do? Call `aMethod` from `FirstClass` in your `SecondClass`?

Comment: No, just lazily instantiate it, ignore the methods

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For some reason, a lazy property needs an explicit type annotation if its
initial value refers to `self`. This is mentioned on the [swift-evolution mailing list](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160125/007784.html), however I cannot explain *why* that is
necessary.

With

```
lazy var first: FirstClass = FirstClass(second: self)
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

your code compiles and runs as expected.

Here is another example which demonstrates that the problem occurs
also with `struct`s, i.e. it is unrelated to subclassing:

```
func foo(x: Int) -> Int { return x + 1 }

struct MyClass {
    let x = 1

    lazy var y = foo(0)            // No compiler error
    lazy var z1 = foo(self.x)      // error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'
    lazy var z2: Int = foo(self.x) // No compiler error
}
```

The initial value of `y` does not depend on `self` and does not need a
type annotation. The initial values of `z1/z2` depend on `self`,
and it compiles only with an explicit type annotation.

**Update:** This [has been fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/9920) in Swift 4/Xcode 9 beta 3,
lazy property initializers can now reference instance members without explicit `self`, and without explicit type annotation. (Thanks to @hamish for the update.)

Comment: W.r.t. "some reason": `self` may be of type `SecondClass` or a subclass type of `SecondClass`. This means the return type of some method of `self` may differ at runtime depending on what `self` is in the class hierarchy. If we were to use the return value of such a class method to lazily instantiate `first`, then we couldn't know at compile time the type of `first` (due to overriden return type in subclass), hence the requirement for explicit type annotation of `first`. Now, this shouldn't be an issue when  using `self` as an argument to an initializer, but possibly the case above generalizes.

Comment: (where by _"return type of some method `self` may differ at runtime"_ I refer to the case where the subclass introduces a new same-name method with same method parameters but different return type; yielding an ambiguous method choice in case `self` is a subclass object and if the lazy variable were not to have been explicitly type annotated. It's weird, though, that the compiler can't infer type e.g. from a supplied explicit return type when using a closure to instantiate the lazy var, e.g. `lazy var first = { () -> FirstClass in FirstClass(second: self) }()`).

Comment: @dfri: Thanks for your response. However, the problem seems to be unrelated to subclassing, I have added an example.

Comment: Also mentioned here: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160125/007784.html, but I haven't found the rationale for it yet.

Comment: I see, the mystery remains unsolved. Meanwhile, categorized as type inferrence weirdness, I guess.

Comment: (W.r.t. swift-evo thread: interesting that apple dev Joe Groff is the one who mentions that, as far as he knows, lazy vars cannot refer to `self` (so maybe the type annotation is a semi-heck of a not fully complete feature))

Comment: Thankfully, this quirk [is fixed in Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/9920) (specifically the build that ships with Xcode 9 beta 3) :)