# Initialize lazy instance variable with value that depends on other instance variables

Tags: swift, swift3, lazy-evaluation

The following initialization currently produces this error in the line that calls `getEventCalendar`:

> Cannot use instance member 'getEventCalendar' within property
>   initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.

Is there any suitable way for initializing the `lazy` instance variable with a value that depends on other object-type `instance variables` of `self` (not just `self` [alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118429/swift-lazy-instantiating-using-self)) ? I've e.g. tried turning `getEventCalendar` from a method into a function, but this does not help either.

```
class AbstractEventCalendarClient {

  let eventStore: EKEventStore
  let entityType: EKEntityType

  lazy var eventCalendar = getEventCalendar()

  init(eventStore: EKEventStore, entityType: EKEntityType) {
    self.eventStore = eventStore
    self.entityType = entityType
  }

  func getEventCalendar() -> EKCalendar? {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Related (almost duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118429/swift-lazy-instantiating-using-self.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a once-only executed closure which captures properties of `self` and use these at execution (= first use of the `lazy` property). E.g.

```
class Foo {
    var foo: Int
    var bar: Int
    lazy var lazyFoobarSum: Int = { return self.foo + self.bar }()

    init(foo: Int, bar: Int) { 
        self.foo = foo 
        self.bar = bar
    }
}

let foo = Foo(foo: 2, bar: 3)
foo.foo = 7
print(foo.lazyFoobarSum) // 10
```

W.r.t. to your own attempt: you may, in the same way, make use of help (instance) functions of `self` in this once-only executed closure.

```
class Foo {
    var foo: Int
    var bar: Int
    lazy var lazyFoobarSum: Int = { return self.getFooBarSum() }()

    init(foo: Int, bar: Int) { 
        self.foo = foo 
        self.bar = bar
    }

    func getFooBarSum() -> Int { return foo + bar }
}

let foo = Foo(foo: 2, bar: 3)
foo.foo = 7
print(foo.lazyFoobarSum) // 10
```

Comment: Yes, smart. I am now using this verbatim line: `lazy var eventCalendar: EKCalendar? = { return self.getEventCalendar() }()`.

Comment: @Drux: `lazy var eventCalendar: EKCalendar? = self.getEventCalendar()` should also work, that was suggested in a (now deleted) answer from @Hamish.

Comment: @Drux Note that, as Hamish showed in his (now deleted) answer, you needn't wrap such a single instance method call in a closure itself, but can simply use `lazy var eventCalendar: EKCalendar? = self.getEventCalendar()` without the closure. The closure method can be convenient if you want to include more logic in the lazy instantiation of the `eventCalender` (in your case, such logic is now contained in the `getEventCalender` method).

Comment: @MartinR you beat me to it by 10 seconds x)

Comment: 8 seconds, to be exact :)

Comment: @dfri So apparently just the explicit type information was missing (in which case this question is really very similar to the linked one.) The verbatim line now reads `lazy var eventCalendar: EKCalendar? = self.getEventCalendar()`. Thx for all help received.

Comment: @Drux I believe Hamish's answer was more spot on w.r.t. the your error message (whereas my verbose asnwer was a bit off track, more focused on lazy property instantiation in general): the explicit type annotation, in addition to prefixing the instance method by `self.`, were the two missing items.

Comment: @Drux My apologies for deleting my answer so prematurely – I was just going into a lecture and saw Martin's linked Q&A, and at a quick glance I thought it would be a suitable dupe target. Although looking at it again, while *very* similar, the solution to this problem differs in that you need an explicit reference to `self` in order to use an instance member. For that reason, I have now undeleted my answer :)

Comment: @Hamish Thx for your (now undeleted) answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's a confusing error message (which you may well want to [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org) on). The problem is just a quirk of `lazy` properties – they currently require an explicit use of `self` in order to access instance members, as well as an explicit type annotation when doing so (which has been previously noted in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118429/swift-lazy-instantiating-using-self)).

Therefore you need to say:

```
lazy var eventCalendar: EKCalendar? = self.getEventCalendar()
```