# How to assign method to variable with [unowned self] semantic

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

Example:

```
class A {
   var fn: (() -> ())? = nil
}

class B {
   let a = A()
   init() {
      a.fn = someFn
   }

   func someFn() {
   }
}
```

Now we have cyclic reference, because `B` owns `A` by direct ref `a` and `A` implicitly owns `B` by `self` owned in `fn` closure (correct me if I'm wrong).

Possible solutions is:

1. <s>weak var fn is not good for my case because I'm assigning not only methods.</s> `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types`.
2. `a.fn = { [unowned self] in self.someFn() }` is correct solution, but too verbose.

Is there any other solutions?

Comment: Well `weak var fn` won't compile as you cannot apply the `weak` attribute to function types ;)

Comment: Related: [How to remove strong reference cycle from closure from method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899051/how-to-remove-strong-reference-cycle-from-closure-from-method)

Comment: @Hamish yes. The questions is same, thx. And yes my first solution is wrong and second is the single possible solution.

Comment: [This question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift) might be useful...