# Swift function as parameter within a class

Tags: swift, function

I'm a swift beginner, so be gentle...

I'm having trouble assigning a function as a parameter.

I have defined this struct:

```
struct dispatchItem {
   let description: String
   let f: ()->Void

   init(description: String, f: @escaping ()->()) {
      self.description = description
      self.f = f
   }
}
```

I make use of this within a class called `MasterDispatchController` like so:

```
class MasterDispatchController: UITableViewController {

   let dispatchItems = [
      dispatchItem(description: "Static Table", f: testStaticTable),
      dispatchItem(description: "Editable Table", f: testEditableTable)
   ]

    func testEditableTable() {
        //some code
    }

    func testStaticTable() {
        //some code
    }
```

etc.

Then I have a table view in my code that dispatches out to whichever function was clicked on (there are more than just the two I showed in the code above, but that's unimportant) like so

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      dispatchItems[indexPath.row].f()
   }
```

So...  The compiler is not happy with this.  It says when I am defining the dispatchItems let statement:

> Cannot convert value of type '(MasterDispatchController) -> () -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> ()'

I figure... ok... I'm not sure I exactly understand this, but it seems like the compiler wants to know what class the callback functions are going to come from.  I can see why it might need that.  So I kind of blindly follow the pattern the compiler gives me, and change my struct to:

```
struct dispatchItem {
   let description: String
   let f: (MasterDispatchController)->()->Void

   init(description: String, f: @escaping (MasterDispatchController)->()->()) {
      self.description = description
      self.f = f
   }
}
```

Great the compiler is happy there, but now when I try to call the function with `dispatchItems[indexPath.row].f()` it says:

> Missing parameter #1 in call

The function has no parameters, so I got confused...

I thought maybe it was asking me for the instance of the object in question which would make some sense... that would be "self" in my example, so I tried `dispatchItems[indexPath.row].f(self)` but then I got an error:

> Expression resolves to an unused function

So I'm kind of stuck.

Sorry if this is a stupid question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the idea behind all this code? cause it might be you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I almost certainly am doing it wrong.  :)

Comment: This is a testing app for my learning of iOS and Swift.  I have a table view that is filled with a large number of little tests.  For example, in one little test, I make a new view controller that shows off custom drawing views.  In another I try making a collection view.  Basically I'm writing a big app where I try lots of different things.  This code is a dispatcher for calling all those little tests.  At runtime, when I click on the table element, I run that little test in question.

Comment: if you are just starting and testing, then just make `switch indexPath.row {case 0: callFunc1() case1: callFunc2() default: CallSomeDefault()}` and call function you need this way. because passing function to a model is wrong.

Comment: Well that's what I WAS doing... I was irritated by the fact that I had multiple switch statements going on.  One where I displayed the text for the table, and one where I dispatched out to the functions.  I wanted that logic all in one place (hence the dispatchItems array).

Comment: What exactly _is_ the question? What precisely do you want to know / do?

Comment: just a note: name your struct uppercased to distinct it from a variable (usage of your struct definition)

Comment: @muescha - Yes, of course. Stupid oversight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to refer to the instance methods `testStaticTable` and `testEditableTable` in your instance property's initialiser *before* `self` is fully initialised. Therefore the compiler cannot partially apply these methods with `self` as the implicit parameter, but can instead only [offer you the curried versions](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/) – of type `(MasterDispatchController) -> () -> ()`.

One might be tempted then to mark the `dispatchItems` property as [`lazy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html), so that the property initialiser runs on the *first access* of the property, when `self` *is* fully initialised.

```
class MasterDispatchController : UITableViewController {

    lazy private(set) var dispatchItems: [DispatchItem] = [
        DispatchItem(description: "Static Table", f: self.testStaticTable),
        DispatchItem(description: "Editable Table", f: self.testEditableTable)
    ]

    // ...
}
```

<sup>(Note that I renamed your struct to conform to Swift naming conventions)</sup>

This now compiles, as you now *can* refer to the partially applied versions of the methods (i.e of type `() -> Void`), and can call them as:

```
dispatchItems[indexPath.row].f()
```

*However*, you now have a retain cycle, because you're storing closures on `self` which are strongly capturing `self`. This is because when used as a value, `self.someInstanceMethod` resolves to a partially applied closure that strongly captures `self`.

One solution to this, which you were already close to achieving, is to instead work with the curried versions of the methods – which *don't* strongly capture `self`, but instead have to be applied with a given instance to operate on.

```
struct DispatchItem<Target> {

    let description: String
    let f: (Target) -> () -> Void

    init(description: String, f: @escaping (Target) -> () -> Void) {
        self.description = description
        self.f = f
    }
}

class MasterDispatchController : UITableViewController {

    let dispatchItems = [
        DispatchItem(description: "Static Table", f: testStaticTable),
        DispatchItem(description: "Editable Table", f: testEditableTable)
    ]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dispatchItems[indexPath.row].f(self)()
    }

    func testEditableTable() {}
    func testStaticTable() {}
}
```

These functions now take a given instance of `MasterDispatchController` as a parameter, and give you back the correct instance method to call for that given instance. Therefore, you need to first apply them with `self`, by saying `f(self)` in order to get the instance method to call, and then call the resultant function with `()`.

Although it may be inconvenient constantly applying these functions with `self` (or you may not even have access to `self`). A more general solution would be to store `self` as a `weak` property on `DispatchItem`, along with the curried function – then you can apply it 'on-demand':

```
struct DispatchItem<Target : AnyObject> {

    let description: String

    private let _action: (Target) -> () -> Void
    weak var target: Target?

    init(description: String, target: Target, action: @escaping (Target) -> () -> Void) {
        self.description = description
        self._action = action
    }

    func action() {
        // if we still have a reference to the target (it hasn't been deallocated),
        // get the reference, and pass it into _action, giving us the instance
        // method to call, which we then do with ().
        if let target = target {
            _action(target)()
        }
    }
}

class MasterDispatchController : UITableViewController {

    // note that we've made the property lazy again so we can access 'self' when
    // the property is first accessed, after it has been fully initialised.
    lazy private(set) var dispatchItems: [DispatchItem<MasterDispatchController>] = [
        DispatchItem(description: "Static Table", target: self, action: testStaticTable),
        DispatchItem(description: "Editable Table", target: self, action: testEditableTable)
    ]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dispatchItems[indexPath.row].action()
    }

    func testEditableTable() {}
    func testStaticTable() {}
}
```

This ensures that you have no retain cycles, as `DispatchItem` doesn't have a strong reference to `self`.

Of course, you may be able to use `unowned` references to `self`, such as shown [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39899051/2976878). However, you should only do so if you can *guarantee* that your `DispatchItem` instances don't outlive `self` (you would want to make `dispatchItems` a `private` property for one).

Comment: Very well explained.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help @ErikWestwig

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Swift treats class methods and functions differently under the hood. Class methods get a hidden `self` parameter (similar to how it works in Python), which allows them to know on which class instance they were called. That's why even though you declared `testEditableCode` as `() -> ()`, the actual function has type `(MasterDispatchController) -> () -> ()`. It needs to know on which object instance it was called.

The correct way to do what you're trying to do would be to create a closure which calls the correct method, like such:

```
class MasterDispatchController: UITableViewController {

   let dispatchItems = [
      dispatchItem(description: "Static Table", f: {() in
        self.testStaticTable()
      }),
      dispatchItem(description: "Editable Table", f: {() in
        self.testEditableTable()
      })
   ]

    func testEditableTable() {
        //some code
    }

    func testStaticTable() {
        //some code
    }
```

If you're familiar with JavaScript, the `{() in ...code...}` notation is the same as `function() { ...code... }` or the same as `lambda: ...code...` in Python.

Comment: What do you mean "*You can't pass `self` to your methods either*"? With a given `(MasterDispatchController) -> () -> ()`, you can totally apply it with `self`, given that `self` is a `MasterDispatchController` instance. You just have to call the resultant function, e.g `f(self)()`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that works, but I'm not able to test right now. I'll remove the part about not being able to pass self. I still think using closures would be more idiomatic/readable in this case.

Comment: @Hamish - but I didn't know that syntax!  I just wrote f(self).  I didn't write f(self)()...  And by the way, when I did that, it worked!

Comment: I'll admit I didn't know class methods behaved as curried functions, but that does make your error make sense. When you did f(self), it returned a function of type `() -> ()` which you never called, so that's what the compiler was complaining about.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  f(self)() was the thing I was missing.  That makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to achieve what you want.

Implement protocol with parameters you want:

```
protocol Testable {
    func perfromAction()
    var description: String { get set }
    weak var viewController: YourViewController? { get set } //lets assume it is fine for testing
}
```

Accessing your `UIViewController` like this is not quite right, but for now it is ok. You can access labels, segues, etc.

Create `Class` for each test you want:

```
class TestA: Testable {
    var description: String
    weak var viewController: YourViewController?
    func perfromAction() {
        print(description) //do something
        viewController?.testCallback(description: description) //accessing your UIViewController
    }
    init(viewController: YourViewController, description: String) {
        self.viewController = viewController
        self.description = description
    }
}

class TestB: Testable {
    var description: String
    weak var viewController: YourViewController?
    func perfromAction() {
        print(description) //do something
        viewController?.testCallback(description: description) //accessing your UIViewController
    }
    init(viewController: YourViewController, description: String) {
        self.viewController = viewController
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

You can add some custom parameters for each `Class`, but those 3 from protocol are required.

Then your `UIViewController` would be like

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    var arrayOfTest: [Testable] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arrayOfTest.append(TestA(viewController: self, description: "testA"))
        arrayOfTest.append(TestB(viewController: self, description: "testB"))
        arrayOfTest[0].perfromAction()
        arrayOfTest[1].perfromAction()
    }

    func testCallback(description: String) {
        print("I am called from \(description)")
    }
}
```