# Instance member **buildName** cannot be used on type **BuildingName**

Tags: swift, lazy-loading

[image]

In my custom cell, I created instance member 'buildingName' and 'detail',
but I cannot use 'buildingName' in 'detail' lazy load method, how to resolve it?

Comment: instead of sharing image, share code.

Comment: Related: [Initialize lazy instance variable with value that depends on other instance variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867568/initialize-lazy-instance-variable-with-value-that-depends-on-other-instance-vari)

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly use `self` inside `lazy`.
Check [this article](http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/2016/02/28/being-lazy/) for more information