# Putting a function into a tuple produces a "cannot convert value of type" error

Tags: arrays, swift, compiler-errors, swift3

I'm working with a collection view, and I'm trying to make a array of tuples, containing the reuse identifier, the cell's type, and the function to call to set up the cell in `tableView(_:cellForItemAt:)`.

So far so good, except for the function. Xcode complains in the array's declaration that it

> "Cannot convert value of type '(AddASpotInfoVC) -> (UICollectionViewCell) -> UICollectionViewCell' to expected element type '(UICollectionViewCell) -> UICollectionViewCell'

`AddASpotInfoVC` is the view controller's class. Here's the array's initialization itself:

```
typealias cellFunc = (_ aCell: UICollectionViewCell) -> UICollectionViewCell
let reuseIdentifiers: [(String, UICollectionViewCell.Type, cellFunc)] = [
    ("AddASpotInfoPicCell", AddASpotInfoPicCell.self, picCellFunc),
    ("AddASpotInfoNameCell", AddASpotInfoNameCell.self, nameCellFunc),
    ("AddASpotInfoDescCell", AddASpotInfoDescCell.self, descCellFunc),
    ("AddASpotInfoTagsCell", AddASpotInfoTagsCell.self, tagCellFunc)]
```

And all the functions in the array (for now) are in an extension of the view controllers' class (not that it should be relevant, I think...) and look like this

```
func picCellFunc(aCell: UICollectionViewCell) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return aCell
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong in my array's initialization?

Comment: Try removing all but one array element, and adding them back one by one, to see whether it's a problem with some or all of them.

Comment: AddASpotInfoPicCell.Type is not equal UICollectionViewCell.Type. Its a different type.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use the instance method in the initialization of the `reuseIdentifiers` variable. You can move the initialization to a method (e.g. viewDidLoad) or make it a lazy property. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855137/viewcontroller-type-does-not-have-a-member-named, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867568/initialize-lazy-instance-variable-with-value-that-depends-on-other-instance-vari for similar (not identical) problems.

Comment: @shallowThought : AddASpotInfoPicCell is a subclass of UICollectionViewCell, declared as `class AddASpotInfoPicCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
}`, so it's good

Comment: @JimMatthews Yup, built the array's tuple progressively, everything just went haywire when I added the functions ^^ But thanks ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function implementation can depend on other variables. So it requires you to declare functions as static. Use:

```
static func picCellFunc (aCell: UICollectionViewCell) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

Inside your array use:

```
AddASpotInfoVC.picCellFunc
```

Edit: You can also move array initialisation code into one of your functions or initialisers.

Comment: That's just perfect. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

If your functions are not using any state, it does make sense to make them class or static methods like  Adamsor suggests.

But if you do want your methods to read/write any variables in your viewController instance, you can use a lazy var for the tuple array, and reference the methods using self, like this:

```
lazy var reuseIdentifiers: [(String, UICollectionViewCell.Type, cellFunc)] = [
    ("AddASpotInfoPicCell", AddASpotInfoPicCell.self, self.picCellFunc),
    ("AddASpotInfoNameCell", AddASpotInfoNameCell.self, self.nameCellFunc),
    ("AddASpotInfoDescCell", AddASpotInfoDescCell.self, self.descCellFunc),
    ("AddASpotInfoTagsCell", AddASpotInfoTagsCell.self, self.tagCellFunc)]
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of it. But when lazy loading, couldn't the array not be initialized when it's called by the CollectionViewDataSource methods ?

Comment: It will allways be initialized the first time you call it: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID257

Comment: Good to know ! One thing though, for future readers, seems like Swift (at least Swift3) doesn't allow for lazy let. Has to be var.