# Access self in swift lazy var

Tags: closures, swift3, lazy-initialization

How can I access 'self' within a lazy stored property closure definition?

This gives a compiler error:

```
lazy var foo = { () -> UIViewController in
    return self
  }()
```

And so this:

```
lazy var foo = { [unowned self] () -> UIViewController in
    return self
  }()
```

But I can access any property (e.g. `self.bar` ) without any problem.

Comment: Care to share the compiler error you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift lazy instantiating using self](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38118429/2976878)