# Type inference when using lazy instantiation

Tags: swift, type-inference, lazy-initialization

Why does type inference on Swift not work here when using lazy instantiation of a property?

```
class GameView: UIView {
    private lazy var animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self)
    ...
}
```

I get an error in relation to the use of `self`:

> Cannot convert value of type ‘(NSObject -> () -> GameView)’ to
>   expected argument type UIView

(Not sure whether the error is meaningful or not-- perhaps I'm not understanding it properly)

...However when it is explicitly typed, then there is no error:

```
class GameView: UIView {
    private lazy var animator: UIDynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Report it as a bug.

Comment: That seems just to be a current restriction if the initial value refers to `self`. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/38118926/1187415 which has a link to the swift-evolution mailing list mentioning the problem.