# iOS lazy var UIBarButtonItem target issue

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, lazy-evaluation, target

I found this UIBarButtonItem target issue unconsciously when using lazy var initialization.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  lazy var barButtonItem1 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(action1))
  lazy var barButtonItem2: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(action2))
    return barButtonItem
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(barButtonItem1.target, barButtonItem2.target)
  }
}
```

The printed results showed that barButtonItem1.target was nil, and barButtonItem2.target was self, which seems crazy!
I got this issue when i use barButtonItem1's lazy var writing, and then i found that barButtonItem1's action can never be called, and finally the issue was barButtonItem1.target was nil.

I don't know why this happens, however i'm pretty sure this is a bug.
Does anyone know something about this? I will really appreciate it if you can explain about it.

Comment: I don't think you're doing `barButtonItem1` correctly. First `lazy var` must be declared with a data type. Second, you're just setting it's value like a regular var. Please read: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-lazy-variables

Comment: The declaration of barButtonItem1 should be correct, according [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

Comment: According to [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html), the declaration of barButtonItem1 should be correct. However i tried what you said to add a data type declaration for barButtonItem1, and it behaves well now. I still don't know what causes this.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your comment!

Comment: You should not implement the bar button like that. Why do you need this type of declaration?

Comment: I declare it with lazy because it maybe not used in my scene, what's the matter here? And Do you have any idea about my problem? Thank you for replying

Comment: @Mannopson what's wrong with lazy initialization of a UIBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Explanation below is my guess*. And unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to give a comment so let me give you an answer.

My guess: this is a compiler bug.

---

First, I crafted a small extension of UIBarButtonItem. (second parameter is not of `Any?` but `UIViewController?`)

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    convenience init(barButtonSystemItem systemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem, targetViewController: UIViewController?, action: Selector?) {
        // call the initializer provided by UIKit
        self.init(barButtonSystemItem: systemItem, target: targetViewController, action: action)
    }
}
```

Then I tried to initialize the lazy stored variable with the code below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var barButtonItem1 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, targetViewController: self, action: #selector(action))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(barButtonItem1.target)
    }
    func action() { }
}
```

Then compiler raised error and say

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> ViewController' to
>   expected argument type 'UIViewController?'

which suggests that compiler failed to determine that `self` is of `ViewController`. (The initializer provided by UIKit would compile because the second parameter is of `Any?` which accepts value of type `(NSObject) -> () -> ViewController`.)

But when give type annotation to the lazy variable like

```
lazy var barButtonItem1: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, targetViewController: self, action: #selector(action))
```

source code happily compiled and `barButtonItem1.target` was set to `self`.

I believe the type annotation helped compile. Above is the reason I guess the issue you faced is caused by a compiler bug.

---

**See also:** there are reported problems similar to the issue you faced. Both of them are concluded as a compiler bug.

[Swift lazy instantiating using self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118429/swift-lazy-instantiating-using-self/38118926#38118926)

[Type inference when using lazy instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546060/type-inference-when-using-lazy-instantiation)

Comment: Thank you! So it's really a compiler bug, hope apple would fix it soon. For now, let's just add type annotation.