# UIPanGestureRecognizer doesn't work without specified type

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I've created my custom View like that:

```
class CircleToggleView: UIView {

lazy var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panHandler))

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initializeView()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initializeView()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2
}

private func initializeView() {
    self.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

func panHandler() {
    print("pan")
}

}
```

Nothing fancy, just print "pan" on every pan gesture. Everything is working but what is interesting if I change first line:

```
lazy var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panHandler))
```

to this:

```
lazy var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panHandler))
```

the handler is not getting called anymore. I can't figure why, can anyone explain me that? Why I have to explicitly declare type?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html well, you can in this link that lazy variables are not created untill it is used. and you have to give specific type  of lazy varibales to use it. or check this http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/

Comment: It doesn't make sense that leaving out the type of the `lazy var` would change the behavior. Type inference should let the compiler figure out its type, and if it **can't** infer the type I would expect a compiler error. Why is your `panGesture` lazy in the first place? Try getting rid of the `lazy` qualifier.

Comment: It's not working without lazy too ;>

Comment: Related (dupe?): http://stackoverflow.com/q/38118429/1630618

Comment: OK, thanks. So the reason is that i specified target as self ;)