# Compilation error when initialising a property with type initialiser that contains a closure

Tags: swift

Could you explain why this error occurs and what would be the best to overcome this issue?

```
class A {

    init(_ closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        print("")
    }
}

class B {

    var s: String?

    lazy var a = A {

        self.s = ""
    }
}

error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'
        self.s = ""
        ^~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy property needs an explicit type annotation if its initial value refers to self. So, You need to explicitly write type `A`

```
lazy var a:A = A {
self.s = ""
}
```

Comment: Here is the detailed description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118429/swift-lazy-instantiating-using-self

Answer (score 0):

As *[@Sahil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5634556/sahil)* pointed out in his answer, for some obscure reasons, a lazily stored property requires a type annotation, whenever it depends on `self`. Your code would turn into:

```
class B {
    var s: String?
    lazy var a: A = A {
        self.s = ""
    }
}
```

with explicit type annotation with `A`.