# Cannot use instance member within property initializer, setting the variable to lazy doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Other SO questions point out to use lazy before the variable, but that doesn't seem to work in this case.

I still get this error,

> Cannot use instance member 'defaults' within property initializer;
>   property initializers run before 'self' is available

where am I getting it wrong ?

```
class UserData{

    let defaults        = UserDefaults.standard
    lazy var userDataDict    = defaults.object(forKey: "UserDataDict") as? [String: String] ?? [String: String]()


    static func setMobileNumber(mobileNumber: String){

        userDataDict["mobileNumber"]         =   mobileNumber

    }
}
```

Comment: You need an explicit type annotation in Swift 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118429/swift-lazy-instantiating-using-self. This has been fixed in Swift 4.

Comment: You cannot set an instance property in the static setMobileNumber method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
lazy var userDataDict: [String : String] = { 
    defaults.object(forKey: "UserDataDict") as? [String: String] ?? [String: String]()
}()
```

**However**, this will only set `userDataDict` once (the first time it is accessed), and you won't see any changes/updates done to `UserDefaults.standard` after that.

I recommend you use a **computed property** instead:

```
var userDataDict: [String : String] { 
    guard let dict = defaults.object(forKey: "UserDataDict") as? [String: String] ?? [String: String]() else {
        return [:]
    }
    return dict
}
```

(it isn't such  a costly operation to do lazily only once, anyway)

Also, I don't see the point in having a copy of `UserDefaults.standard` as a property of your object; perhaps it's just best to have:

```
// remove: 
// let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

var userDataDict: [String : String] {
    guard let dict = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UserDataDict") as? [String: String] ?? [String: String]() else {
        return [:]
    }
    return dict
}
```

As a last temark, all these amkes your dictionary "read only" as far as the User Defaults database is concerned; if you wish to preserve any changes, your property needs a **setter** too:

```
var userDataDict: [String : String] {
    get {
        guard let dict = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UserDataDict") as? [String: String] ?? [String: String]() else {
        return [:]
        }
        return dict
    }
    set (newValue) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "UserDataDict")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```