# Xcode 8 doesn't compile type-inferred property that is using `self`

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

Here is a snippet of Swift code that compiles in Xcode 9.0, but not in Xcode 8.3.3:

```
class MyClass {

    let myNumber: NSNumber = 3
    lazy var myPropertyUsingSelf = Int(self.myNumber)

}
```

> error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'
>
> private lazy var myPropertyUsingSelf = Int(self.myNumber)
>
> ```
>                                     ^~~~
> ```

I found that removing type inference solves the issue:

```
class MyClass {

    let myNumber: NSNumber = 3
    lazy var myPropertyUsingSelf: Int = Int(self.myNumber)

}
```

**But I do not understand why that's the case.
Can someone explain that?**

*n.b. Using a closure works too.
But Swift cannot infer the type from a closure and forces you to explicitly declare the closure returning type, so I suppose it's simply the same solution as above.*

Comment: Try with lazy var myPropertyUsingSelf {.... }

Comment: If you are initializing a var on init, why is it defined as lazy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [swift evolution mailing list](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160125/007784.html), a lazy property needs an explicit type annotation if its initial value refers to self, the reason is not cleared why it's needed.

If the type is specified then it's runs without any issues, like in your case.

```
class MyClass {

    let myNumber: NSNumber = 3
    lazy var myPropertyUsingSelf: Int = Int(self.myNumber) //works when type Int is specified for lazy property

}
```

**Update**: The issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/9920) in Swift 4/Xcode 9 beta 3, lazy property initializers can now reference instance members without explicit self, and without explicit type annotation.

(reference this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118429/swift-lazy-instantiating-using-self) post)